# How to prevent double rows on DB with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to insert a **Song** entity to a DB (**Song** has ManyToOne association with **Album**).
The problem I encounter is that when I insert for example 2 songs with the same Album, Hibernate inserts The Album twice to the DB (with different ids).
I would like to know what is the best way to create only one Album.
(I am saving "Song" using  class SongRepository extends JpaRepository with simple "save" method)

thanks for the help

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class SongController {

@Autowired
private SongService songService;

@PostMapping(value = "/song")
public ResponseEntity<Void> add(@RequestBody Song song) {
    songService.add(song);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

SongService

```
@Service
public class SongServiceImpl implements SongService {

@Autowired
private SongRepository songRepository;

@Transactional
@Override
public Song add(Song song){
    return songRepository.save(song);
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface SongRepository extends JpaRepository<Song, Long> {
Song save(Song song);
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "SONGS")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"num", "name", "rate", "album"})
public class Song implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;


@Column(name = "NUMBER")
private int num;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "RATE")
private int rate;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ALBUM", referencedColumnName="ID", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="ALBUM"))
private Album album;

}




@Entity
@Table(name = "ALBUMS")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"name", "year"})
public class Album implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "YEAR")
private int year;
}
```

Comment: show "main" code

Comment: added the controller and service

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Comment: Hibernate is building the schema according to the annotations

Answer (score 0):

I would make the album object have a `List<Song>` with a `@OneToMany` relationship. Give the Song object the albumId as a foreign key. Then you can call save on the album in one go if you use an `AlbumRepository`.